# Correct way to create /etc/machine-id from python

Tags: python, uuid, systemd

I want to create systemd's `/etc/machine-id` from a python script instead of using `systemd-machine-id-setup`. I am preparing a rootfs and I don't want to depend on systemd being installed on the host.

My current code looks like this:

```
from uuid import uuid4
f = open("machine-id", "w")
f.write(uuid4().hex + "\n")
f.close()
```

Is this the correct way of doing it? Is it the correct byteorder? Did I miss anything?

If needed, please provide correct code and/or references.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. See the [Documentation](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/machine-id.html). Its a text file so byteorder is not relevant here.
Also see the code that handles/generates it:
The `make_v4_uuid` function and the place where it is called from at line 221 in
https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/master/src/libsystemd/sd-id128/sd-id128.c

Although personally I would make it:

```
from uuid import uuid4
with open("machine-id", "w") as f:
    f.write(uuid4().hex + "\n")
```

Comment: byteorder might be interesting, as the three two byte tuples in the middle can be interpreted as uint16, so even the hex representation could be affected. Thanks for verifying! And yes, your code looks much nicer.